# How to enable soap on php buildpack for cloud foundry

Tags: php, soap, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I'm using the following buildpack https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack and cannot get soap to work.

I've got the following .bpconfig/options.json file:

```
{
  "PHP_EXTENSIONS": ["bz2", "zlib", "curl", "mcrypt", "mbstring", "mysqli", "mysql", "gd", "zip", "openssl", "soap"],
  "PHP_VERSION": "PHP_55_LATEST"
}
```

but I'm still getting the following error message when trying to invoke a Web Service:

> "AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SoapClient' not found in /home/vcap/app/htdocs/appelWS.php on line 4\n'"

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

The directory name is wrong. Try using

```
.bp-config/options.json
```

Doc is [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/docs/config.md)